# Trouble iterating through an iteration of elements

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

So just trying to programatically iterate through a specific stacklayout's children, and obtain the children of those elements. The first element I iterate through, gives me the option of a `Children` object. As such:

`var TextContainerChildren = TextContainer.Children;`

TextContainer is a StackLayout holding a bunch of other stacklayouts. As such:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="TextContainer" Padding="10,10,10,0">
              <Label Text="What's New" FontSize="20" />
              <!--<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="0,10,0,10">
                <Label Font="15" Text="Version 2.3.1 - January 9, 2017" TextColor="Blue" />
                <Label Font="15" Text=" &#8226; Breaking News Push Notifications. Users can now subscribe to breaking news push notifications that display an alert on your phone when a breaking news story is published." />
                <Label x:Name="LabelEmailHelp" Font="15" Text="" />
              </StackLayout>-->

              <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="0,10,0,10">
                <Label Font="15" Text="Version 2.3.1 - January 12, 2017" TextColor="Blue" />
                <Label Font="15" Text=" &#8226; Minor bug fixes." />
                <Label x:Name="LabelEmailHelp" Font="15" Text="" />
              </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

So now I try to iterate through `TextContainer.Children` as such:

```
foreach(Xamarin.Forms.View el in TextContainerChildren)
{
    if(el.GetType() == typeof(Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout))
    {
        var j = el;
    }
}
```

The issue is, `el` doesn't let me access the children. (trying to do `el.Children` doesn't work, and by that I mean, when I look at the object in debugging there is no `Children`). However, when I'm debugging, I can see `el` is a StackLayout, and in `base` I see the Children object.

Is there any way to access `base` of an element? If not, anyone know how I can read the children of an iterated element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to cast it

```
if(el.GetType() == typeof(Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout))
{
    StackLayout j = (StackLayout)el;

    // now you can use j.Children
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, just figured this out, will accept your answer when I can. Thanks.